# Why won't this conky config stick to background in i3wm?

Tags: conky

Having issues with my i3wm conky config.
When "own_window = yes" the clock displayed in this file always stays on top of all my windows. And it won't display if I set the value to no.
my conky file:
(The other colours, templates, and fonts are used in different conky files which are having the same issue.)

```
double_buffer yes

alignment middle_middle

border_width 1
cpu_avg_samples 2
default_color white
default_outline_color white
default_shade_color white
draw_borders no
draw_graph_borders yes
draw_outline no
draw_shades no


own_window_class conky
own_window yes
own_window_type desktop
own_window_transparent 
own_window_hints below,undecorated,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
update_interval 1.0


show_graph_scale no
show_graph_range no

use_xft yes
xftalpha 0.1
xftfont Droid Sans:size=12

color1 3d454d # 30
color2 5c6773 # 45
color3 7a8a99 # 60
color4 99acbf # 75
color5 b7cee6 # 90
color6 e0f0f6 # 96
color7 77b5f2 # 95
color8 a6a6a6 # 65
color9 1f3040 # 25

template0 font Andarilho Font # Headlines
template1 font Streetvertising # Data
template2 font we are alien!! # Arrows


TEXT
${voffset 0}${offset 0}${color8}${$template0:size=120}${time %H:%M}${$template0}
```

Anyone know what to do here?

Comment: Strange. I just tried this on my machine (Arch, cinnamon) and the clock is shown below all windows. Have you ever seen this sort of thing work with a tiling WM? I'd be surprised if it worked on i3wm, really.

Comment: I used to have a bigger conky config with different things, but they kept pushing eachother around(example: when the clock changed from 13:41 to 13:42 the width increased and the day behind got pushed further towards the right.) So it used to work on i3..

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this question is as written
[here](https://faq.i3wm.org/question/3829/conky-on-desktop.1.html). `own_window_type` should be set to `override`.

Comment: for those using newer versions `own_windown_type` needs the single quotes around it to work now, therefore you should use `own_window_type = 'override'`